# Seleniun Hashmap(String, WebElement) not returning WebElement when passed String

Tags: java, selenium, hashmap

I've written a java class (CustomerHistoryMapping), which contains a HashMap(String, WebElement), as in the code below (first section of code) 
My overall aim is to be able to use a given WebElement, depending on the string I pass to the HashMap class.

```
package com.xxxxx.data;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class CustomerHistoryMapping {

  @FindBy(xpath = "(//td/span[text()='Preferred Name']/../following-sibling::td[3]/span/span)[1]")
  public WebElement txaNewPreferredNameValue;

  @FindBy(xpath = "(//td/span[text()='Mobile']/../following-sibling::td[3]/span/span)[1]")
  public WebElement txaNewMobileValue;

  @FindBy(xpath = "(//td/span[text()='Email']/../following-sibling::td[3]/span/span)[1]")
  public WebElement txaNewEmailValue;

  @FindBy(xpath = "(//td/span[text()='Mailing Street']/../following-sibling::td[3]/span/span)[1]")
  public WebElement txaNewMailingStreetValue;

  @FindBy(xpath = "(//td/span[text()='Mailing City']/../following-sibling::td[3]/span/span)[1]")
  public WebElement txaNewMailingCityValue;

  @FindBy(xpath = "(//td/span[text()='Mailing Zip/Postal Code']/../following-sibling::td[3]/span/span)[1]")
  public WebElement txaNewMailingPostCodeValue;

  @FindBy(xpath = "(//td/span[text()='Mailing State/Province']/../following-sibling::td[3]/span/span)[1]")
  public WebElement txaNewMailingStateValue;

   Map<String, WebElement> mapping = new HashMap<String, WebElement>();

  public CustomerHistoryMapping() {
    mapping.put("preferredName", txaNewPreferredNameValue);
    mapping.put("mobile", txaNewMobileValue);
    mapping.put("email", txaNewEmailValue);
    mapping.put("address", txaNewMailingStreetValue);
    mapping.put("city", txaNewMailingCityValue);
    mapping.put("postcode", txaNewMailingPostCodeValue);
    mapping.put("state",txaNewMailingStateValue);
  }

  public WebElement getValue(String mapKey) {
    return mapping.get(mapKey);
  }

}
```

However, when I call getValue("preferredName") - (see second snippet of code) and check the logs this is what's printed:

Str is: preferredName, And ele is: null

```
      objCustomerHistoryMapping = new CustomerHistoryMapping();
      WebElement ele = objCustomerHistoryMapping.getValue("preferredName");
      logger.info("Str is: preferredName, And ele is: " + ele);
```

So the WebElement in the HashMap isnt being pulled back - any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `PageFactory.initElements(...)` in order to initialize your fields with the elements on the page. You can add it as the last line of your constructor.

Unless you have used `initelements` all your fields will be referring to `null`.